# How to get selected form from a TScrollBox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tscrollbox

I am creating some forms inside a scroll box, dynamically.

When I click on a created form I want to get some values that are stored in that particular form to the parent form. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

I hope it doesn't sound confusing. Here is a screen shot of what I am doing.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the forms store an Index to them in their Tag property. I'd be storing references to dynamic forms in an array or list to access them later, but even if your just creating them with the scrollbox as the owner they'll have an index for scrollbox.Controls[x]

I'm guessing the you have (or need) some event on the form/labels/images as an onlclick event so your user can select a form, then you can change the backcolor (or label color) to show that the form is selected. At this point you could update the Tag property in the parent scrollbox to match the Tag of the form (I'm assuming your storing the forms in an array or list).  You can then use the Tag as a "Selected Index" property.

From that point it's fairly trivial to access the forms members from the index.